# SQL STRING_AGG() to generate sql string dynamically with multiple variables

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is an issue I am facing while using STRING_AGG.

Lets say I have a table, `#table_A` (This is a temp table)

```
   ID     CheckColumn
   1        GJAHR
   2        LMNON
```

Then I declare two variables viz.

```
   DECLARE @v1_YYYY varchar(4)
   DECLARE @v2_MM   varchar(4)
   SET @v1_YYYY = '2022'; 
   SET @v2_MM ='07';
```

Then I am trying to generate a string like below:

```
   GJAHR EQ @v1_YYYY AND LMNON EQ @v2_MM
```

I know I can use STRING_AGG() like below

```
   DECLARE @sql varchar(100);
   SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(x.checkColumn + 'EQ' + '''' + @v1_YYYY + '''' , ' AND ') 
                 FROM  #table_A
```

But this would create the below string:

```
   GJAHR EQ @v1_YYYY AND LMNON EQ @v1_YYYY
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: you did not uses the variable `@v2_MM` in the concatenation at all.

Comment: @Squirrel: Can you please help me here in providing a code snippet? In fact I am also trying figure out how to use `@v2_MM`  in that `STRING_AGG()` function

Comment: Do you have only 2 rows in the `#table_A` ? If you have more than 2 rows, how do you want to perform the concatenation ?

Comment: @Squirrel: Yes there are only two rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case` expression to check the ID value and decide which variable to participate in the concatenation

```
   SELECT @sql  = STRING_AGG(checkColumn + 'EQ' + '''' 
                + case when ID = 1 then @v1_YYYY else @v2_MM end
                + '''' , ' AND ') 
   FROM  #table_A
```